# How add a custom value to a drop down in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a drop down list in excel which is getting values from a series of cells (implemented using Data Validation). Say "Portfolio A", "Portfolio B" and "Portfolio C"

I wanted to add a custom value on top of the list. I mean the list of values I have  is say name of portfolios. On one of the worksheet I want to allow user to either select one portfolio value or All.

Since "All" is not the name of portfolio so I am not willing to add "All" to the cells from where I am sourcing values for portfolios.

Is there any way I can add "All" on top of list of values OR is there anyway I can let user select more than one value from list?

Comment: Usually *Data Validation* fills a **single cell**.  If the user picks *"All"*, should multiple cells be filled or should all the values be placed in the same cell ??

Comment: If user select "All" then I like "All" to be displayed in the cell itself. In further calculation I will assume that user hasn't selected any particular portfolio which would mean user is interested in analysis of all portfolios.

Answer (score 0):

As far as i know, you cannot add a custom value to data validation field. You need to have "All" included in your selection range.

An alternative option would be to use Form or ActiveX Controls in Developer mode.